# Pull Wordpress Blog Post into Angular JS

Tags: javascript, apache, angularjs

I want to pull in the blog feed from something like http://blog.neosavvy.com/?feed=rss2 for use in an Angular application that doesn't live on the same domain.

I was going to use ProxyPass, however ProxyPass won't work with the /?feed=rss2. Is there a rewrite rule I can use to avoid the Cross Domain issues that Javascript has when fetching things that aren't in the same URL.

I use AngularJS's service to fetch the feed content just like any other service.

Here is the code I am using to fetch the blog rss:

```
$scope.getBlogPost = function() {
    $http({method:'GET', url:'http://blog.neosavvy.com/?feed=rss2'}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data returned");
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data not returned");
        });
}
```

Here is the error I receive - thus the need for a proxypass or some alternative.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blog.neosavvy.com/?feed=rss2. Origin http://local.something.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) or [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/)

I made an example with the latter, which you can check here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Plb1fz?p=preview

Instead of using the `$http` service, you would use the Google Feed API and your controller would look like this

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://blog.neosavvy.com/?feed=rss2");
  feed.load(function(result) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.entries = result.feed.entries;
    })
  });
});
```

Notice that since the scope changes from outside Angular, a call to `$apply` is needed to notify Angular.

Some considerations, first you'll need to add the following scripts to your document

- https://www.google.com/jsapi
- angular-sanitize.min.js

Then, it'd be necessary to bootstrap your angular app manually since the Google Feed API must be loaded first

```
google.load("feeds", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){     
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
});
```

Since the feed contains html, you declare the *ngSanitize* module as a dependency

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

To show the entries in the feed then you could use the `ngRepeater` to iterate over the entries received and of course sanitize the html with the `ng-bind-html` directive.

```
<div ng-repeat='entry in entries'>
  <h1>{{entry.title}}</h1>
  <div ng-bind-html= "entry.content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or shorter by using JSONP:
````$http.jsonp('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', {params: {v: '1.0', q: '<feedurl>', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'}}).success();````   .. Reference: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide

Comment: I just did a write up on how to do just this based on @BettySt 's idea. http://golightlyplus.com/how-to-display-a-wordpress-feed-in-an-angularjs-app/

Comment: @BettySt You cannot use this inside of Angular as this cannot find $http

Comment: @CodedContainer you need to inject $http in your controller ;) then you can use it like this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

The URL in question is an RSS feed. There are no cross-site scripting considerations to be made. RSS is an XML format intended to be pulled from anywhere.

Just about any JavaScript framework will do what you're asking. ["RSS" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS).